# Pass wordpress products to shopify checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, shopify

I have a WordPress site where users can pin their products. I'm planning on adding an add to cart button which will pass the WordPress products to Shopify cart. Is that possible? If it is, how? If not, any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is now Shopify for WordPress, where you can use an entire theme or use a plugin that add Shopify functionality: https://www.shopify.ca/blog/113145925-introducing-shopify-for-wordpress

The plugin lets you add products with buy buttons into any sidebar, page or blog post. It also includes a pop-out shopping cart.

Good luck!